# Need single row with all the values from previous row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two rows as below in Oracle as below:
[image]

I want a single rowas below:
[image]

Can you please help me with the requirement?

Thanks.

Comment: As most of us already repeated before -> Please share your sample input and output as texts rather than images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select host, database, . . ., column,
       max(HCDE) as HCDE,
       max(NOPI) as NOPI,
       max(INF_CLAS) as INF_CLAS
from t
group by host, database, . . ., column;
```

The `. . .` is for all the other columns.

Comment: Hi @Gordon,
I am already using that, but not getting the desired result.

Comment: @user3901666 - "...but not getting the desired result" is not particularly helpful. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the question tags and include the code you've tried and the results or errors you're getting. Without that there isn't much anyone can do to help you. Thanks.

Comment: @user3901666 . . . In that case, the values in the one of the first seven columns might *look* the same, but they are not in fact the same.

Comment: Thanks  @GordonLinoff, I applied trim and now its working as expected.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff !! Can you please upvote the question. I am currently serving a question ban. I will try to be more accurate with my questions.